# Mysql View replace only one column with static valiue?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE VIEW `myview` AS select * from mytable
```

Is it possible to replace just one column with a static value inside the view? Eg `mytable.myvalue = 'view'`? Or would I then have to list all columns in the select, like:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview` AS 
  select col1
       , col2
       , ...
       , coln
       , 'view' as myvalue 
    from mytable
```

Comment: Yes, you must list all output columns one-by-one, and use according expression (static literal) for a column to be replaced. Remember - MySQL do this with your `SELECT *` during the execution plan building firstly, and then it processes the query with separate columns list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above gives a correct answer, because there's no wildcard that means "all columns except the ones I don't want."

You could use the wildcard if you want an *additional* column:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview` AS select *, 'view' as myvalue from mytable
```

But if you want one of the columns matched by the wildcard to be replaced by your constant value, you'll have to spell out the columns.

Here's a trick that may make it easier: when you use `*` in the definition of the view, MySQL will expand that to the column names. You can then use `SHOW CREATE VIEW myview` and it will display a full CREATE VIEW statement, with all the columns named explicitly. Then you can use your mouse to copy and paste that string into any editor interface, so you don't have to type all the columns. You only need to edit it in two places:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `myview` AS 
       ^^^^^^^^^^ add this
  select col1
       , col2
       , ...
       , coln
       , 'view' as myvalue 
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ omit the column you don't want, and add the constant
    from mytable
```

Then you can run the edited version and it replaces the initial view you created with a new view with one column you wanted replaced.